# Got navCtrl issue in ionic 3 when try to use it inside provider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

I am trying to make user navigate to Login Page when his/her token expires. The point is that inside token interceptor provider it shows red line under do here:

```
  return next.handle(_req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
```

and also under this line under navCtrl:

```
this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TokenProvider } from './token/token';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  IonicPage,
  NavController,
  NavParams,
  AlertController,
  LoadingController
} from 'ionic-angular';


@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private tokenProvider: TokenProvider) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return fromPromise(this.tokenProvider.GetToken()).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headersConfig = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json'
        };
        if (token) {
          headersConfig['Authorization'] = `beader ${token}`;
        }
        const _req = req.clone({ setHeaders: headersConfig });
        return next.handle(_req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        // do stuff with response if you want
      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
          // or show a modal
        }
      }
    });
      })
    );
  }
}
```

What is wrong and how to fix these 2 issues?

Comment: pass `NavController` in side your constructor.
`constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)`

Comment: @Najamussaqib issue with 'do' still exists:
 return next.handle(_req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {

Comment: if you are having issue with your `HTTP` request. please check this: https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/

Comment: it shows redline only under do

Answer (score 0):

you are using `this.navCtrl`. Before that we need to import the `NavController`. like the link(https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/)

```js
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

class MyComponent {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
  service(){
  this.navCtrl.push('MyPage');
  }
}
```

Comment: What about the issue with do?
 return next.handle(_req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {